# How to build query in symfony 2 that can update a field of datetime type?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

The expireTime field in the entity is \DateTime type, I need to update this field and my code is as below:

```
$query = $dq->update()
    ->set('u.token', $dq->expr()->literal($token))
    ->set('u.isDeleted', false)
    ->set('u.expireTime', $dq->expr()->literal($expireTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')))
    ->where('u.email= :email')
    ->setParameter('email', $email)
    ->getQuery();
```

but I got the following error:

```
stackoverfExecute query in BaseDao error:[Syntax Error] line 0, col 84: Error: Expected Literal, got ','
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you´re passing a String, dont you have to pass a dateTime Object ? so rather  `->set('u.expireTime', $expireTime)`

Comment: Thanks for your help , but this  code can not work also.

Comment: Try removing `$dq->expr()->literal()`. The line should look like: `->set('u.expireTime', $expireTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'))`

Comment: Thanks for your help ,but this code still not work with error as below "  Execute query in BaseDao error:[Syntax Error] line 0, col 117: Error: Expected end of string, got '00'  "

Comment: are you sure in your mapping this field type is a datetime ? maybe your definition is the error show code

Comment: yes ,I am sure the field type is Date time .                                                                            * @var \DateTime
* @ORM\Column(name="expire_time", type="datetime", nullable=false)